# My application is restarted when opening from the lock screen

Tags: android

Step to reproduce the issue:

I'm using a SM-T580 Android tablet with Android 8.1.0.

- Goes into settings screen of the device -> lock screen -> -> shortcuts -> set the application on one of the two sides of the screen.
- Open the application the normal way and navigate to another activity than the launcher activity.
- Lock the device (pressing the power button).
- Press the power button -> lock screen is visible.
- Open the application by swiping it to its opposite corner of the screen.
- The application restart to the launcher activity.

Maybe this is useful, the device is locked with a model (the 9 points model).

I have two questions about this:

- Why it is happening?
- Is their a way to prevent it? Keeping the state of the application when opening via lock screen?

#### UPDATE

I created a sample project to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/Martin-Hogge/lock-restart-sample

Here are the logs after reproducing the scenario I explained above:

```
2019-02-25 10:17:23.549 20482-20482/com.example.testlock D/TEST_LOCK: Application onCreate
2019-02-25 10:17:23.694 20482-20482/com.example.testlock D/TEST_LOCK: MainActivity onCreate
2019-02-25 10:17:24.024 20482-20482/com.example.testlock D/TEST_LOCK: MainActivity onStart
2019-02-25 10:17:24.032 20482-20482/com.example.testlock D/TEST_LOCK: MainActivity onResume
2019-02-25 10:17:27.036 20482-20482/com.example.testlock D/TEST_LOCK: MainActivity onPause
2019-02-25 10:17:27.079 20482-20482/com.example.testlock D/TEST_LOCK: SecondActivity onCreate
2019-02-25 10:17:27.109 20482-20482/com.example.testlock D/TEST_LOCK: SecondActivity onStart
2019-02-25 10:17:27.114 20482-20482/com.example.testlock D/TEST_LOCK: SecondActivity onResume
2019-02-25 10:17:27.646 20482-20482/com.example.testlock D/TEST_LOCK: MainActivity onStop
2019-02-25 10:17:29.104 20482-20482/com.example.testlock D/TEST_LOCK: SecondActivity onPause
2019-02-25 10:17:29.132 20482-20482/com.example.testlock D/TEST_LOCK: SecondActivity onStop
2019-02-25 10:17:34.297 20482-20482/com.example.testlock D/TEST_LOCK: SecondActivity onDestroy
2019-02-25 10:17:34.315 20482-20482/com.example.testlock D/TEST_LOCK: MainActivity onDestroy
2019-02-25 10:17:34.363 20482-20482/com.example.testlock D/TEST_LOCK: MainActivity onCreate
2019-02-25 10:17:34.449 20482-20482/com.example.testlock D/TEST_LOCK: MainActivity onStart
2019-02-25 10:17:34.455 20482-20482/com.example.testlock D/TEST_LOCK: MainActivity onResume
```

We can see that the `MainActivity`and the `SecondActivity` are both being destroyed when I reopen the app through the lock screen.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why did I get a "-1" vote?

Answer (score 0):

If you will look carefully at the log you have provided, you will notice that `onDestroy` is called for both activities. Once `onDestroy` is called, the only way back into the app is by restarting it (by calling `onCreate`).

Because the `onDestroy` is called, you will need to save your activities state to **persistent storage** (using `SharedPreferences` or a settings file, whatever fits your need).

Comment: I saw that onDestroy was called but: 1) I don't understand why it is called. If we reopen the application through the home screen instead of the lock screen the onDestroy is not called. 2) Should I persist the name of the current activity in my persistent storage? Otherwise how should I know on which activity the user was before locking the screen?

Comment: @MHogge onDestory is called by the underlying OS to free up memory. If you want to read more about it, here is a link to the official docs https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy().
2. You dont need to, if you use SharedPreferences, it is relevant only for that app. Each app has its own SharedPreferences.

Comment: Thank you for your time but I'm not sure we're understanding each others. My issue is that the entire application is restarted (because all active activities are being destroyed). Is their a way to get the user back to its last current activity? I know each app has its own SharedPreference but apart from saving the name and the state of the last active activity I do not see another way to make the re-opening of an application from lock screen behaving the same way as if we were re-opening it from home screen (usual way). But maybe that's the only way to go.

Comment: @MHogge oh, if you want to know which activity was the user on, then yes, you need to save on what activity he/she were on prior to the screen lock.

Comment: Having the same issue. Does anybody has the answer. I also would like to understand what is happening